# How can I establish schedules on opportunity products (with daily installment period excluding weekends)?

Tags: apex, date, opportunity-lineitem, product, opp-lineitemschedule

Background:

1. Under **Opportunity** tab, I will go and create a new Opportunity.
2. In the Opportunity Detail, there should be a button to add **Product**
3. When adding new **Product**, I click the 'Establish' button under Schedule (as shown below):

[image]

After establishing the schedule daily, I save it and can see the view below:

[image]

Question :
How can I establish schedules on opportunity products with daily installment period **excluding weekends**?
As you can see the daily schedule also includes weekends which I don't want.

How I want the schedule to display for daily up to 10 days:

- Date Quantity
- 1/05/2017    500
- 2/05/2017    500
- 3/05/2017    500
- 4/05/2017    500
- 5/05/2017    500
- 8/05/2017    500
- 9/05/2017    500
- 10/05/2017   500
- 11/05/2017   500 (Since 6/7 May = weekend, populate 11 May)
- 12/05/2017   500 (Since 6/7 May = weekend, populate 12 May)

I tried using Workflow rules capturing the criteria easily like so:

```
AND(Product2.HasQuantitySchedule = True,
Product2.HasRevenueSchedule = False,
ISPICKVAL( Product2.QuantityScheduleType , 'Divide amount into multiple installments'),
ISPICKVAL(Product2.QuantityInstallmentPeriod , 'Daily') )
```

but the field update cannot edit the Opportunity product schedule.

So I was thinking of using apex where I can store the variable :

```
private OppLineItem opplineitem = [SELECT id,ScheduleDate FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule where type = 'quantity']
```

Then somehow edit/delete all ScheduleDate which are weekends into future business days. Am I on the right track or is there a better solution?